# Selecting the newest records for 6 unique columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table of 6 currency conversions, it's updated almost daily. Unfortunately the way the software works is it inserts new rows rather than updating the existing ones. My previous SELECT was as follows

```
SELECT FROM_CURRENCY_ID, XCHG_RATE 
FROM
(
SELECT TOP 6 FROM_CURRENCY_ID, XCHG_RATE 
FROM SHARED_CURRENCY_EXCHANGE 
WHERE NOT FROM_CURRENCY_ID = 'CAD' 
ORDER BY RECORD_CREATED desc
) t 
ORDER BY FROM_CURRENCY_ID
```

The issue now is some records got updated while others didn't so my query returns duplicate values for one of the currencys and nothing for one. I need it to output the 6 unique FROM_CURRENCY_IDs and their XCHG_RATE with the newest RECORD_CREATED dates

I've been trying a group by to exclude the duplicate rows with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with x as 
(select row_number() over(partition by from_currency_id order by record_created desc) rn, * from shared_currency_exchange)
select from_currency_id, xchg_rate from x 
where rn = 1
```

This gives the most recent record a rownumber 1 and you can use the cte with this condition.

Comment: There is a missing bracket, otherwise it looks good.  And it's missing the `FROM_CURRENCY_ID = 'CAD'` condition.

Comment: So this would take the place of my subquery?

Comment: @AlexFerreira..you don't need a sub query..try this query as is

Comment: @vkp yeah that did it!